# Stripe - Get risk score from checkout.session.completed event

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a webhook for `checkout.session.completed`. There is no information about risk score in the object I receive. How can I get the risk evaluation information for my customers' payments?

I can see the risk score from Stripe dashboard, but I also need it in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`risk_score` field](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object#charge_object-outcome-risk_score) is set on the Charge [object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object#charge_object) associated with the payment. This object is **not** directly available on the Checkout Session [object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object) or events.

In order to retrieve these details, you'd need to make an additional API request in your webhook handler. My recommendation would be to [retrieve](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/retrieve) the associated Payment Intent using the `pi_xxx` ID from the [`payment_intent` field](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-payment_intent) on your `checkout.session.completed` event, and [expand](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) the [`latest_charge` field](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-latest_charge). The response will include the full Charge object, including the required `outcome.risk_score` field.

This will look something like this using the [`stripe-node` library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node):

```js
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.retrieve('pi_xxx', {
  expand: ['latest_charge']
})
```